# Intersecting overlapping polylines using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, intersection, linear-referencing

I have 4 multipart polyline shapefiles (download a sample dataset [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71994585/xchangewd.zip)).

The geometries are identical, except for the length of segments in each shapefile. They represent 4 variables describing an identical shoreline. From these 4 overlapping polylines, I would like to create a resulting polyline that has segments for each unique set of the 4 input lines.

My approach was to use an intersect. This, however, breaks down when I try to run it on 4 huge feature classes.

My question is whether there is a more efficient way to combine polyline attributes stored in separate layers. I thought a union would be good, but it only works on polygons. Spatial Join seems inefficient, as I would end up with many to many joins for a single segment. Turning the segment end points into a point layer, then splitting the line at those points?

I have access to arcpy, PostGIS, and shapely.

Has anyone had experience doing this before on large datasets? Is there a more efficient way to store these variables?

Comment: You can run ST_Union in Postgis on Lines too. I don't completely understand your problem description, but when I have insanely complex intersection problems (millions of polygons against millions of polygons), I usually break it down into smaller chunks -- divide and conquer style that you learn in algorithms classes -- and then merge the results afterwards. This involves writing plpgsql (my language of choice) functions, but you could do the same in shapely, I'm sure. I have got orders of magnitude performance boosts over a straight intersection/union with spatial join approach.

Comment: When I starte reading I was thinking about your point based method. (splitting one of the feature class at the end points of the other feature classes).

Comment: The DropBox is giving an Error (404), but in any event, to avoid link rot, I think it would be better providing just a picture and description of the data rather than a download.  When you say that intersect "breaks down" do you mean that it throws an error or something else?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a use case for [Overlay Route Events](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/linear-ref-toolbox/overlay-route-events.htm) from the Linear Referencing toolbox:

> Overlays two event tables to create an output event table that
>   represents the union or intersection of the input.
>
> ...
>
> - Line-on-line, line-on-point, point-on-line, and point-on-point event overlays can be performed.
> - The input and overlay events should be based on the same route reference.

The "same route reference" sounds like your "identical shoreline" that can be easily turned into a route ready for dynamic segmentation.

You are trying to "intersect overlapping polylines" which sounds like a "line-on-line ... event overlay" to me.

Comment: Your answer is useful, as this was the advice I was given by ESRI as well. Unfortunately, however, the size of the layers was still too large, so we had to split them and then combine them in the end.

Comment: However, I no longer have access to ArcGIS, but am working on a solution using shapely.