# How to intersect two polyline layers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, linear-referencing

I have two line shapefiles that overlap 50% of the time. I want to generate a new single shapefile that includes attributes of both datasets AND no duplicate segments.

A short segment from one layer will split the longer segment from the other and they will combine to form a new segment made of the overlapping segments. I have Arcmap 10.1 license.

Example: First layer = street centerline shapefile. Second layer = road improvement layer which is only PART of the centerlines. Centerline layer is not segmented, so a spatial join would apply attributes from 2nd layer to entire segment of first layer - which would not be accurate. So I want to combine BOTH.

[image]

Comment: Could you edit your question to make it a little more clear?  If two shapefiles overlap, are you trying to create three shapefiles (one of the intersecting areas and the originals without the intersecting sections?) On the overlapping areas, how do you determine which attributes to keep?

Comment: Merge them 1st. Dissolve, no multiparts. Remove all attributes. Calculate midpoints for resulting segments. Spatial join 1:M with merge. Summarise table using segment id and 1st-last statistics for attributes. Transfer summary to segments table

Comment: I'm confused by your last paragraph - the link to the duplicate question should be appearing at the top of your question, and the answer appears under the question, but here is a direct link to the answer (which is to use [Overlay Route Events](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/linear-ref-toolbox/overlay-route-events.htm) for your line-on-line overlay): http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/164606/115